# Laplace Transform Property for faster solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$
f(t):=
\begin{cases}
3\cos(2t) & t<5 \\
4\sin(3t) & 5 \leq t \leq 9 \\
0 & t>9.
\end{cases}
$$

The above function I know how to solve using straight Laplace Transformation by Integration. However these integrals are not very quick to calculate by hand. I was told that there is a property involving Laplace Transformations that may make this problem quicker. Any suggestions which properties would help to find the Laplace transform in the most efficient manner?

Comment: Do you mean in this situation add the Integrals of the first two functions together or is that only part of what you are getting at?

Comment: just saw your link sorry for the question

Comment: These tables are very informative and the examples are as well. My last conceptual question is what do I do with the constraints on t?

Comment: I am going to attempt to add it myself for you to review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite your function using the [*Heaviside Unit Step function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and then we can use the Shifting Property and Laplace Transform table. I would recommend practicing this with these [*examples*](http://www.math.psu.edu/shen_w/250/NotesLaplace.pdf).

**Step 1:** Lets plot your piece-wise function. We get:

[image]

**Step 2:** Lets rewrite the piece-wise function using the unit-step function as a single function.

We get:

$$f(t) =  3 \cos(2t) + (4 \sin(3t) - 3 \cos(2t)) u(t-5) + (0 - 4 \sin(3t)) u(t - 9)$$

Lets plot this function and it should be identical to the first one.

[image]

**Step 3**

Now, using the [*Laplace Table*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) and the shifting property, we can easily write the Laplace Transform.

The final result will be:

$$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = -\dfrac{3 e^{-5 s} (s \cos(10) - 2 \sin(10))}{s^2 + 4} + \dfrac{
 4 e^{-5 s} (3 \cos(15) + s \sin(15))}{s^2 + 9}$$